# Tree in python: recursive children creating

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I have a class called rectangle with two parametres (SX and SZ). I need to do a function that will devide me a first rectangle in two parts with a line in a random place on the wider dimension, then these two new rectangles will be divided in two, then  four etc. I use a simple tree structure and a function like this:

```
def devide(self):
    if (self.SX>self.SZ):                #check which dimension is bigger
        temp=randint (int(self.SX/4), int(self.SX*3/4))  #generate random from x/4,3x/4           
        left=rectangle(temp, self.SZ)             #create nodes
        right=rectangle(self.SX-temp, self.SZ)
        self.addChild(left) 
        self.addChild(right)
    else:
        temp=randint (int(self.SZ/4), int(self.SZ*3/4))              
        up=rectangle(self.SX, temp)                 
        down=rectangle(self.SX, self.SZ-temp)
        self.addChild(up)
        self.addChild(down)

    for c in self.getChilds():
        while (c.level()<3):     ####why doesn't it work?:(
            c.devide()
```

And the function `level()`— it should (but it doesn't) return a value of how many levels are between the root and the actual node:

```
def level(self): 
    root=self
    a=0
    while root.isRoot()==False: 
        a+=1
        root=root.getParent()
    return a
```

Important things for me are:

- how to limit those divisions (for example, to have only 1+2+4+8 nodes)? I mean, there are no static variables in Python and my function `level()` doesn't work properly.
- how to get the access to the youngest children (for example, to have them in array)

I am new in programming, especially in Python. Could somebody help me, please?

Comment: To add a limitation on the number of levels just pass it into the `divide` function via a keyword like so: `def divide( rectangle, Max_levels=5 )` then each iteration in the recursive call do it such that ` Max_level - 1` and stop refusing once `max_level` reaches 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this: (It is a double-linked (parent knows children and children know parent) binary tree)

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

import random

class Rectangle:
    def __init__ (self, width, height, parent = None):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []

    @property
    def level (self):
        return 0 if not self.parent else 1 + self.parent.level

    def split (self):
        if self.children: raise Exception ('Already split')
        ratio = random.random () * .5 + .25 #split between 1/4 and 3/4
        if self.width > self.height:
            width = int (ratio * self.width)
            self.children = [Rectangle (width, self.height, self),
                Rectangle (self.width - width, self.height, self) ]
        else:
            height = int (ratio * self.height)
            self.children = [Rectangle (self.width, height, self),
                Rectangle (self.width, self.height - height, self) ]

    def splitUntilLevel (self, maxLevel):
        if maxLevel <= self.level: return
        self.split ()
        for child in self.children: child.splitUntilLevel (maxLevel)

    def __str__ (self):
        s = '{}{} x {}\n'.format (' ' * (2 * self.level), self.width, self.height)
        for child in self.children: s += str (child)
        return s

r = Rectangle (100, 100)
r.splitUntilLevel (3)
print (r)
```

Comment: Just... wow. Thank you very much, your code is so elegant and definite. It will be useful, I am really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `a += 1`, not `a = +1`.

Also, calling `divide()` on an object will not increase its own `level`, so you'll never get out of the loop. You should check the level on the terminal leaves of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

What does addChild(up) and addChild(down)? You could associate to each rectangle an integer that contains the self level, much more easy and if you want to limit the depth of the tree when generating a new rectangle just evaluate the result of: 2^h  h-> depth of the tree.

Comment: It's just adding a new node (called up or down) as a child to an actual node- i need this function for some graphic stuff and that's why called it like that. Thank you for this idea with a new integer, I think I will use it.